# Laravel Echo Server, no listening to channels but works with events

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-echo

i'm using Redis, with socket.io, laravel-echo-server and VUe.

In my local machine it's working just fine but the only problem when i uploaded and made the configuration in the server is that laravel-echo-server is not even trying to authenticate nor sending an error, but works fine when i send or broadcast an event:

When i run an event, it reflects in Laravel-echo-server:
**PRODUCTION SERVER IMAGE**
[image]

But it's not even trying to listen or authenticate, this is my listening code in Vue:

**PRODUCTION SERVER IMAGE**

```
mounted() {
        //LARAVEL ECHO, SOCKET.IO, REDIS, etc
        Echo.private(`messages.${this.user.id}`)
            .listen('NewMessage', (e) => {
                console.log("LLEGÓ MENSAJE NUEVO");
                console.log(e);
                this.handleIncoming(e.message);
            });
```

But as i mentioned it does not show anything in Laravel-echo-server console.
With the same configuration this is how it looks in my local machine:

**localhost IMAGE**
[image]

As i said, it does not even try to authenticate or connect to the channel.

This is my laravel-echo-server.json: 
**PRODUCTION SERVER IMAGE**

[image]

Am i missing something?
Why is it working with the events but no listening or at least try to listening to them?

Thank you so much!

**EDIT 1:**

This is part of my .env FILE

**PRODUCTION SERVER IMAGE**

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

This is part of my bootstrap.js
**PRODUCTION SERVER IMAGE**

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: '127.0.0.1:6001' //I CHANGED TO STATICALLY GO TO 127.0.0.1
});
```

And this is part of my config/database.php:

**PRODUCTION SERVER IMAGE**
[image]

In localhost it works just fine, using http:127.0.0.1:8000
and 127.0.0.1:6001 for laravel echo.

the problem is when i upload and configure in my AWS Lightsail, the domain is http://test1.erpnegocios.com and the route in the server is /var/www/html/test1

**EDIT 2:**
I've been reading posts that say that the host in bootstrap.js (socket.io) must be the same host in laravel-echo-server.json, that's why i'm using for both host: '127.0.0.1:6001' (as shown in the images) but the problem persists.

If i run sudo service redis-server stop, laravel-echo console stop working, so i assume that the connection is good, but i can't get clients connecting to channels, nor public or private 
**EDIT 3**
Guys i changed my bootstrap.js and laravel-echo-server.json as follow:
**bootstrap.js**

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001' //El host de laravel-echo-server
});
```

**laravel-echo-server.json**

```
{
"authHost": "http://test1.erpnegocios.com:8000",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

I also opened the port 8000 in my server, now running my laravel-echo-server console, i see:

[image]

Basically it's working now but **only** in public channels, i think the error is related to another config, let me explain you:

the server's main IP is 3.83.87.137
in that server i have multiple projects:
/var/www/html/test1
/var/www/html/erp
/var/www/html/test, etc.
The IP (3.83.87.137) is pointing to /var/www/html/erp, but i'm configuring and using test1 first. I believe that i can't authenticate because pointing my laravel-echo-server.json authHost to 3.83.87.137:8000 is pointing to /var/www/html/erp, am i right? Should i change my configuration so 3.83.87.137 points to /var/www/html/ o i can configure my laravel-echo-server.json authHost to 3.83.87.137:8000/test1?
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: does your .env file are the same (or correctly set) for the following values : REDIS_PREFIX, BROADCAST_DRIVER. If it's can you add the code where you import Echo and socket.io-client?

Comment: @ElieMorin i just updated my question, thank you for your time

Comment: Can you please mark or separate the development code/images from the production code/images? Can you access lightsail with ssh? In production, the code will try to connect to `127.0.0.1`. Are all your local services running in production too? I do use EC2, never use lightsail, will take a look.

Comment: @JonathanMartins i just updated the question, please check it.

Comment: Are that two ports open to public? `6001`, `8000`. Your javascript applications will try to connect to these services. But in production, these services are not running in `127.0.0.1`. Probably `http://test1.erpnegocios.com`. Is `http://test1.erpnegocios.com:6001` and/or `http://test1.erpnegocios.com:8000`

Comment: @JonathanMartins pointed the solution. Your client script try to reach the wrong endpoint. In ```laravel-echo-server.json``` change ```authHost``` for your domain and do the same into bootstrap.js. I use ```window.location.hostname``` to let the script handle dev versus prod.

Comment: @JonathanMartins ElieMorin Guys,, thank you so much, i updated the question (EDIT 3), it's working with public channels, can you please check the UPDATE? Thank you so much for your help and time!

Comment: seems like you need to set REDIS_PREFIX as @elimorin. Laravel prepends prefix to database. See in your Laravel project `config/database.php:126` and you should update your `laravel-echo-server.json` file. In dot notation `databaseConfig.redis.keyPrefix`.